# Issue Using the LARGE & ROW Function to Dynamically Sort

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to dynamical display a sorted column in Column C, based on a list of values in Column A. Traditionally, I've found that using the formula below works well in Column C:

=LARGE(A$1:A$10,ROW(A1)-ROW($A$1)+1)

After obtaining a sorted list of values I then do a VLOOKUP on Column B (person associated to the value) to populate Column D with the associated value, giving me a dynamically sorted list of value/name combinations. However, a problem has arisen in and I can't figure out a solution.

Strangely enough this has never happened before but two individuals have the same value. The problem occurs when I try to do a VLOOKUP for the second duplicate value, I get the name associated with the first individual in both instances of VLOOKUP. How do I force Excel not to duplicate names if the values are identical?

Comment: Use INDEX and AGGREGATE where the AGGREGATE subfunction is 15 and it gets it's *k* parameter from a COUNTIF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) where the row number is returned by an [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) and the AGGREGATE subfunction is 15 ([SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29)) that gets it's *k* parameter from a [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34).

[image: First Second Third result]

The **standard** formulas in D2:E2 are,

```
=LARGE(B$2:B$11, ROW(1:1))
=INDEX(A$2:A$11, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$10)/(B$2:B$11=D2), COUNTIF(D$2:D2, D2)))
'pre-XL2010 alternate for E2
=INDEX(A$2:A$11, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$10)+(B$2:B$11<>D2)*1E+99, , ), COUNTIF(D$2:D2, D2)))
```

Fill down as necessary.

Note that `ROW(1:10)` is the *position within* `A2:A11` and not the actual row on the worksheet. You can substitute your original `ROW(A1)-ROW($A$1)+1` in place of the `ROW(1:1)` if you prefer.

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>